# Nginx with Wordpress subdirectory Setup giving ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_LOCATION

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I do have a reverse proxy towards a docker container running in 8080 from location block "/". I wanted to install WordPress alongside that in subdirectory "/blog" I have this configuration:

```
    server {
server_name www.example.com example.com;
    
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com_access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com_error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   "Connection" "";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:28080;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }

location /blog {
    index index.php index.html;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }
}

}


server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

But this configuration is giving me:

```
ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_LOCATION
```

When I try to access https://example.com/blog

What am I doing wrong? Please help.